# Data Structure to hold repeated data in java

Tags: java

class1, method1, message1,sno1

class1, method2, message2,sno1

class1, method3, message3,sno1

class2, method1, message1,sno2

class2, method2, message2,sno2

Data is hardcoded values that keeps growing.

this data structure should able to provide message? and sno? for any class? and method? as input ...

Comment: SO is here to help you solve problems, not to write code for you. Please submit the code that is giving you problems and ask specific questions.

Comment: I am just a beginner in java & trying to learn of how to solve a requirement. I am trying to read the stacktrace so that i can get a classname, methodname and line no. Using classname and method name would want to read a predefined data (in the format of classname, methodname, description, which i have used enum class). But the requirement that i missed was the format can have repeated classname for different methods also should avoid enums.  Want some help to find out what options do i have to create static data.

Comment: public enum ExceptionEnumClass {

 CLASS1("class1", "This error is from class1", 1),   
 
 CLASS2("class1", "This error is from class2", 2),
 
 CLASS3("class1", "This error is from class3", 3),
 
 CLASS4("class1", "This error is from class4", 4),
 
 CLASS5("class1", "This error is from class5", 5),
 
 TESTEXCEPTIONLOG("TestExceptionLog","This error is from TestExceptionLog", 6);

Comment: Define an object that has "Class", "Method", "Message" and "SNO" attributes. Create an instance of this object assigning the values each time you get data, and store it in an ArrayList of type your object.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a complete answer without more information about where your data is coming from but something like this seems roughly what you want.

Define an object that has Class, Method, Message and SNO attributes:

```
public class DataContainer {

    String className;
    String method;
    String message;
    int sno;

    public DataContainer(String className, String method, String message, int sno){
        this.className = className;
        this.method = method;
        this.message = message;
        this.sno = sno;
    };

}
```

You can create getters and setters for each attribute if you'd rather make them private (better practice).

and then use and ArrayList to store instances of your object. Call it something like this:

```
ArrayList<DataContainer> myDataStructure = new ArrayList<DataContainer>();

while(data){
    myDataStructure.add(new DataContainer(className, method, message, sno));
}
```

To refer to or retrieve your data you can use the syntax:

```
System.out.println(myDataStructure.get(iterator).className);
```